# Print Batch results to a text file?

Tags: file, batch-file, text, printing

I created a batch file to lookup my external ip.

and it works well .

This is the code.

```
    @echo off
>"%temp%\ip.vbs" echo Set objHTTP = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
>>"%temp%\ip.vbs" echo Call objHTTP.Open("GET", "http://checkip.dyndns.org", False)
>>"%temp%\ip.vbs" echo objHTTP.Send()
>>"%temp%\ip.vbs" echo strHTML = objHTTP.ResponseText
>>"%temp%\ip.vbs" echo wscript.echo strHTML
for /f "tokens=7 delims=:<" %%a in ('cscript /nologo "%temp%\ip.vbs"') do set ip=%%a
echo %ip:~1% 
pause
```

What i want is to Print the results to a text file named "IPlog.txt"

and every time i run the bat file it has to do the same thing and print the new results to the next line in the text file. So please can anyone help me with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

... or change your

```
echo %ip:~1%
```

to

```
echo %ip:~1% >>IPlog.txt
```

to run your batch without the additional  " >>IPlog.txt "

Comment: Now can you tell me if i can do a check if that ip exists in the IPlog.txt before it print it there again !!     And if it exists it will print some message like IP exists in the console.

Comment: therefore you need one of the following commands: "find" or "findstr" See help (find /? or findstr /?) to find out which command fits your needs better

Answer (score 1):

Please remove the `pause` command from your code and run the `batch-file` like this

```
mybatch.bat >> IPlog.txt
```

This will append the resulting ip address on to the log file `IPLog.txt` every time you run this batch file.